# Vaadin OSGi Portlet on Liferay 7

Tags: eclipse, liferay, osgi, liferay-7, vaadin8

I'm trying to create a **Vaadin protlet** and deploy it on a **liferay** portal with **OSGI**.
I'm new to this so sorry if its very simple but I don't understand what I'm missing.

[OSGi Portlets on Liferay 7](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/portal/portal-osgi.html#portal.osgi)
is the tutorial that I found in Vaadin's site.

Tutorial says :

> Publishing an OSGi portlet on Liferay 7+ can be done in two ways:
>   using annotations or using properties. Annotating a UI class with
>   @VaadinLiferayPortletConfiguration (available in
>   vaadin-liferay-integration) and making it an OSGi service of type UI
>   is the easiest way to automatically publish the UI as a portlet and
>   configure it to use the correct static resources.

```
@Theme(MyTheme.THEME_NAME)
@VaadinLiferayPortletConfiguration(name = "Vaadin.Tutorial.1", displayName =
"Vaadin Tutorial App")
@Component(service = UI.class, scope = ServiceScope.PROTOTYPE)
public class MyUI extends UI {
...
}
```

I created a maven project with **vaadin-liferay-integration** but Eclipse does not recognize annotations in this tutorial (@VaadinLiferayPortletConfiguration AND @Component ) 
Does any one have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Better place to start is official Vaadin archetype:

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-archetype-liferay-portlet/8.1.6/

Moreover, this a sample portlet I wrote for Liferay 7, very basic but with some tricks:

- https://github.com/ctliv/vaadin-portlet-sample/

Comment: I've downloaded your project but I don't see any bnd files needed for deploying to an OSGI container.Any way can you provide me more information on how I can deploy it on Liferay.
And a documentation about the project structure would be much appreciated

Comment: There are two ways to create a bundle using Maven. First is to use "bnd.bnd" file and the "biz.aQute.bnd":"bnd-maven-plugin" (as in official archetype). Second is to use [Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin] (http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html), which does not use "bnd.bnd" but lists all OSGi manifest entries in the pom.
For the documentation, I'll check if I can do something, but first I'd suggest to read here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/portal/portal-osgi.html